# sql query for report produce wrong result

Tags: sql, left-join

I have this problem regarding sql which i will be using in a webservice if I can get this right. What I wanted to do is create a summary report of a transaction. The transaction have header and lines. In a transaction, we are going to input a many planks. 

After the inputing, I would like to produce a report that would add all the plank that belongs to a category, then multiply all the planks by the price of that supplier so that I can have the total amount. Here is a pic: [image]

below is my sql which produce wrong output:

```
select
      t1.transaction_num,
      wo1.wood_classification_desc,
      wo2.wood_specie_desc,
      sum(t2.board_foot) as total_board_foot,
      su1.price,
      sum(t2.board_foot*su1.price) as total_amount
    from
      "transaction_hdr" t1
      left join "transaction_lne" t2 on (t1.transaction_id = t2.transaction_id)
      left join "supplier" su2 on (t1.supplier_id = su2.supplier_id)
      left join "supplier_price" su1 on (t2.price = su1.price)
      left join "wood_classification" wo1 on (t2.wood_classification_id = wo1.wood_classification_id)
      left join "wood_specie" wo2 on (wo1.wood_specie_id = wo2.wood_specie_id)
    group by
      t1.transaction_num,wo1.wood_classification_desc,su1.price,su2.supplier_name,wo2.wood_specie_desc
    order by transaction_num,wo2.wood_specie_desc
```

Evrytime I run that sql, it produces somthing like this:[image]

the transaction that i test only have five planks. 4 planks under `Mahogany 6" wider - 7ft. up` and 1 `Mahogany 5" wider - 7ft. up`.

Comment: 8 * 13.33 is 106.64. I don't understand the issue?

Comment: yes it is, that was my problem. In my data, I only have one that fall in that category. So it should be only 13.33.

Comment: Please more Description for it Question .
i do not know Target .
thanks .

Comment: @jayAnn: What are the realtinships between the tables?

Comment: t1 is the header, which has the supplier_ID, wood_specie_id, and other. t2 is the line. It has transaction_id, the board_foot, wood_classificatoin_id and price. Wood species are mahogany, narra, yakal, etc. wood classifications are the `mahogany 6wider - 7ft up, mahogany 5wider - 7 ft up.....etc`. I have a transactions that have many lines. Each lines contains planks with different sizes to be computed for board foot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have more than one record in supplier_price with price = 13.33 ? That would be my guess, as all the other joins appear to be on primary keys..

EDIT:

Your problem is that you're joining to supplier_price on the price field, which is not a valid key. Given that your output doesn't take anything from the supplier_price table, I'd be inclined to remove it from the query altogether as below:

```
select
      t1.transaction_num,
      wo1.wood_classification_desc,
      wo2.wood_specie_desc,
      sum(t2.board_foot) as total_board_foot,
      t2.price,
      sum(t2.board_foot*t2.price) as total_amount
    from
      "transaction_hdr" t1
      left join "transaction_lne" t2 on (t1.transaction_id = t2.transaction_id)
      left join "supplier" su2 on (t1.supplier_id = su2.supplier_id)
      left join "wood_classification" wo1 on (t2.wood_classification_id = wo1.wood_classification_id)
      left join "wood_specie" wo2 on (wo1.wood_specie_id = wo2.wood_specie_id)
    group by
      t1.transaction_num,wo1.wood_classification_desc,t2.price,su2.supplier_name,wo2.wood_specie_desc
    order by transaction_num,wo2.wood_specie_desc
```

Comment: 13.33 is not a price. It's a board foot of a plank entry. In a transaction, i may have more than one with 13.33 but in my testing, there's only one

Comment: do you have more than one record in supplier_price with price = 30 (in fact, do you have 8 of them?)

Comment: well thats your problem - you're joining on a value with multiple matches for the join. I don't see any reason for you to join to this table, so would be inclined to make the SQL as above (see edit to original answer)..

Comment: you're answer is right. Thanks. Bad for me I only see this after I have figured it out by myself, and too much time i wasted.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess, that in one of the left joins you have more than one record, which means it give you wrong sum (group by will affect the set after the left join).

Just run the sql without the grouping and check what you get.

So it's probably not the multiplication that causes the problem, it's the sum.

Comment: Now I see, i was wrong in joining tables and some of my tables that i calculate to get the sum is wrong. I just have the correct output just now.

Answer (score 0):

This may solve the issue. But it would help if you provided the relationships between the tables (and the tables' primary keys):

```
select
      t1.transaction_num,
      wo1.wood_classification_desc,
      wo2.wood_specie_desc,
      sum(t2.board_foot)
        as total_board_foot,
      ( SELECT DISTINCT su1.price
        FROM "supplier_price" su1
        WHERE t2.price = su1.price
      ) AS price,
      sum(t2.board_foot) *
          ( SELECT DISTINCT su1.price
            FROM "supplier_price" su1
            WHERE t2.price = su1.price
          )
        as total_amount
    from
      "transaction_hdr" t1
      left join "transaction_lne" t2
        on (t1.transaction_id = t2.transaction_id)
      left join "supplier" su2 
        on (t1.supplier_id = su2.supplier_id)
      left join "wood_classification" wo1
        on (t2.wood_classification_id = wo1.wood_classification_id)
      left join "wood_specie" wo2
        on (wo1.wood_specie_id = wo2.wood_specie_id)
    group by
        t1.transaction_num
      , wo1.wood_classification_desc
      , su2.supplier_name
      , wo2.wood_specie_desc
    order by transaction_num
           , wo2.wood_specie_desc
```

Comment: t1 is the header, which has the supplier_ID, wood_specie_id, and other. t2 is the line. It has transaction_id, the board_foot, wood_classificatoin_id and price. Wood species are mahogany, narra, yakal, etc. wood classifications are the mahogany 6wider - 7ft up, mahogany 5wider - 7 ft up.....etc. I have a transactions that have many lines. Each lines contains planks with different sizes to be computed for board foot.